# aws optional parameter using executeAwsAPI in automation runbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-automation

My goal is to use the following command:

```
aws iam list-users --max-items 10
```

But I want the parameter `max-items` to be optional.

I am using the following runbook (It just the relevant parts):

```
parameters:
  MaxItems:
    type: Integer
    description: (Optional) the maximum number of items
mainSteps:
  - action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    inputs:
      Api: list-users
      Service: iam
      MaxItems: '{{MaxItems}}'
```

The problem is `max-items` don't have default value so is it possible to make this parameter optional?

Comment: Is it cloudformation template? What exactly is your automation document, as you showed only some parts of it.

Comment: @Marcin It's automation runbook as part of Systems Manager